# Drupal, SoundManager 2 and External Links

Tags: drupal-7

I want to show soundmanager style mp3 links on my site.

I configured Drupal 7 for SoundManager 2. It works fine with internal mp3s but it doesn't work with external mp3 urls. I mean when I add

```
<a href="http://site.com/test.mp3">Test</a>
```

the soundmanager style player isn't being showed.